# console logging the python script console output in node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, opencv, stdout

I'm working on opencv python and node.js server in which python script prints out the string "moved" useful for my node server

I'm using 'python-shell' for spawning python script as a child process
but the problem is that i'm working on a video file in opencv and node only console logs only after the cv2.imshow(video window) is exited. I want it to console log the output in node from python script on real-time.

Neither i'm getting the argument in the conditional statement (message === 'moved')

### server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var pyshell = new PythonShell(__dirname + './script.py');

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
  // received a message sent from the Python file script.py (returns "moved" string)
  console.log(message);
  console.log(message + 'hi');
  if(true){
    console.log('hey')
  }
  if(message === 'moved'){
    console.log('hit')
  }
});
```

### Console in Node.js

```
moved
hived
hey
```

also why did 'moved' and 'hi' concatenated to 'hived'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the realtime logging can be done by flushing the stdout in python script

```
print('somestring', flush=True)
```

works fine for flushing in python 3.3+

and the string concatenation overlapping was because the returned string had '\r' in it
I removed '\r' the var with

```
variable.replace(/\n|\r/g, "")
```